# Changing margin in CSS does not change it on website (Cache cleared)

Tags: css, caching, margin

I have a strange issue.
I detected that margin-top needs to be set to 0 for my toggle menu to look well.
I changed this in CSS and cleared my cache but the problem is still there.
Please let me know what should I do to fix this.
You can see live problem here: http://onedayitinerary.com
Thanks!

Screenshot of the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk4CA.png

Answer (score 1):

You didn't target the required selector. When pointing the element in DevTools, check the code that has the most importance on the right hand side.

```css
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did and it still doesn't work. If I check the inspect element, new css is not loaded but the old one without margin-top: 0px;I just realized that only turning off W3 total cache plugin solves the problem, but I really need that plugin. Any idea how can I keep it working and still have this fixed? Thanks!

Comment: I would ask their developers since I have had problems with them too :P

Answer (score 0):

The ul around, has a margin-top:25px; on it. Remove that in the file and it should work.

If you already have done that, try add "style.css?ver=1" to your stylesheet link. Sometimes that will force an stylesheet update.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you need to modify your style.css to fix this issue